# Discord.py - message.content is empty for every message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot and when I run it locally, it works fine; However when I push it to heroku, it doesn't work because message.content is empty for some reason for every message. It was working fine just a few days ago, but it broke now.

main.py code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    print(f'msg1: {msg}')
    print(f'msg: {message}')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == '':
        await message.channel.send('test')
```

requirements.txt:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==2.2.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
gspread==5.3.0
oauth2client==4.1.3
openpyxl==3.0.9
discord==1.7.3
```

Comment: the development branch which you have specified in your requirements file uses the v9 API which has the new message_content privilege intent, instead of putting the github link, put discord.py==1.7.3 (or whatever version you’re using on your pc) And do **not** put discord==1.7.3 in your requirements file!! It’s a clone

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński just started experiencing empty content issues after switching to the dev branch. Is there any way to get the message content from messages when using the dev branch? I've tried turning on PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT but I am still getting empty content parameters.

Comment: the dev version uses the new discord API which has a new privilege intent (message content) @VincentLauffer

Comment: I had message intents turned on too, but turns out I wasnt passing in all of my intents to my client LOL

Answer (score 1):

Go to the dev portal and turn on intents
Then when creating the bot add

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", intents=discord.Intents.all())]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        pass
    else:
        print(message.content)

client.run("token")
```

that should work